# ARM big.LITTLE Performance Counters

Tags: performance, counter, performancecounter, perf

I have recently purchased a development board utilizing Samsung Exynos5422 application processor (Cortex™-A15 2.0Ghz quad core and Cortex™-A7 quad core CPUs). I have tried to extract the performance counters in android using perf v3.0.8; however, none of the counters outputs a value (They are all "not counted"). Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

(The kernel version is 3.10.9)

Comment: Which Cortex cores are used in your chip (Cortex-A15+
Cortex-A7 with GTS)? What is the version of your kernel, what are the config settings of the kernel (/proc/config.gz or /boot/config*)

Comment: And which performance counters you tried to extract?

Comment: The SoC is Samsung Exynos5422 (Cortex™-A15 2.0Ghz quad core and Cortex™-A7 quad core CPUs).

The Linux/Android that is compatible with the device has kernel version 3.10.9. 

I don't have Linux installed at the moment and I could not find any relevant config files on Android. 

I have tried all the available performance counters and they are all <not counted>

Comment: It seems that the A15 core is supported by Linux 3.10.
Was perf built in the system or did you try to compile it from Linux kernel sources?

Comment: I compiled it from the source.

Comment: Are you sure your kernel was compiled with support for hardware performance counters? To check, you could grep `dmesg` or `/proc/kmsg` for `perf`. You should see something like `hw perfevents: enabled with ARMv7_Cortex_A15 PMU driver, 1 counters available`

Comment: No, I'm not sure about it. I ran both commands and none of them shows an output.

Comment: If you purchased an Odroid Board, I've been facing [the same issue](https://github.com/hardkernel/linux/issues/181), and was only able to set A15 or A7 counters, not both (which would require more investigation I guess). Did you find something else since last year?